# Can I use the term 'the desperate' as a kind of 'desperate people'?

Tags: grammar

I'm not an native English speaker.

I have written some lyrics:

> Like **the desperate** waiting for Messiah, I'm just waiting for you.

I want to use the term 'the desperate' for the meaning of 'desperate people'.

Does this sentence make sense?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, however I would say this belongs in the English Stack Exchange instead.

Comment: @MatthewDave Thanks for your reply and sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @MatthewDave please don't suggest [ELU.SE] as a place for non-fluent speakers to ask basic questions that could be resolved by reference to a good dictionary. It would immediately be closed on that site, and even on [ELL.SE]. Stack Exchange users are expected to do some basic research before asking on a site. Poor referrals like this impose an additional community moderation burden on the other site, and are unfair on the user who ends up having their question closed wherever they go.

Comment: @Ododox I recommend you consult a good online dictionary when you have this kind of question: try [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/) or [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/). For further guidance, see [ask]. PS: FWIW, it's a perfectly sensible use of the word. :-)